# Subset nested data frame with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to subset an inner data frame of a nested data frame with `dplyr`?

I have the following nested data frame:

```
library(dplyr)

# Initialise nested data frame
d <- tibble(group = c("A", "B"),
            data = rep(list(NA), 2))

set.seed(1)
d$data[[1]] <- data.frame(x = seq(1:10),
                          y = rnorm(10))
d$data[[2]] <- data.frame(x = seq(1:15),
                          y = rnorm(15),
                          z = runif(15))
```

Let suppose that I only want the rows in the data frame for `group == "A"` where `y >= 0`, while the data frame for `group == B` stays intact. **Edit:** *The two resulting data frames should have the same variables after the operation.*

I was thinking to do something like the line below but in combination with the mutate command, but the `filter(y >= 0)` does not work here. So, how should I do it?

```
d %>% filter(group == "A") %>% select(data) %>% filter(y >= 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could do by doing the `filter`ing inside `map2`

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
    mutate(data = map2(group, data, ~
                                .y %>% 
                                     filter(!(.x == "A" &  y < 0))))
 # A tibble: 2 x 2
 #  group data                 
 #  <chr> <list>               
 #1 A     <data.frame [6 × 2]> 
 #2 B     <data.frame [15 × 3]>
```

Using the reverse comparison, it would be

```
out <- d %>%
         mutate(data = map2(group, data, ~
                         .y %>%
                           filter((.x == "A" & y >=0)|.x != "A")))
out
# A tibble: 2 x 2 
#  group data                 
#  <chr> <list>               
#1 A     <data.frame [6 × 2]> 
#2 B     <data.frame [15 × 3]>

map(d$data, dim)
#[[1]]
#[1] 10  2

#[[2]]
#[1] 15  3

map(out$data, dim)
#[[1]]
#[1] 6 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 15  3
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to `filter` based on two variables (`group` and `y`). However, one of the variables (`y`) is part of a nested variable (`data`). It's much easier to access those two variables via `filter` if you first `unnest` your data. You can then `nest` your data again if you really need to.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Initialise nested data frame
d <- tibble(group = c("A", "B"),
            data = rep(list(NA), 2))

set.seed(1)
d$data[[1]] <- data.frame(x = seq(1:10),
                          y = rnorm(10))
d$data[[2]] <- data.frame(x = seq(1:15),
                          y = rnorm(15),
                          z = runif(15))
d %>%
  unnest() %>%                        # unnest data
  filter(!(group == "A" & y < 0)) %>% # exclude rows where y < 0 for group A
  group_by(group) %>%                 # for each group
  nest()                              # nest data

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#     group data             
#     <chr> <list>           
#   1 A     <tibble [6 x 3]> 
#   2 B     <tibble [15 x 3]>
```

Comment: If I have multiple variables which I have grouped the nested data frame by---lets say: group, colour, age. Can I then in a smart way save those grouping variables before I am unnesting, and feed that the `group_by()` command?

Comment: If you do the `filter` part before you `nest` your data that would be ideal. This will save you time from unnesting and then nesting again. Then, if you want to `nest` based on multiple variables, that's still possible, but feels like it's another question, right? Doesn't have to do with the `filter` issue anymore.

Comment: You can post another question, more relevant to nesting using multiple variables if I wasn't very clear.

Comment: I see your point. It is somehow a different question. My main concern about unnesting all of the data is that it is rather CPU intensive, and when I re-nest, I get the z-variable in the data frame, which I don't want. That is why I want to operate directly on the inner data frame for group `A` right away.

Comment: Ok, so you're looking for a solution that doesn't use unnest. I'll see what I can do.....